# Rails routes and subdomain: unknown url to 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am having an issue with routes, have tried to google but nothing came out so far. Would be great, if someone will able to explain, how works and solution.

Thanks,
Cheers :)

**Sample:**

**1)**

> default url: lvh.me:3000/restaurants

Default url works fine, but once adding any unknown subdomain.

> adding unknown subdomain: `blabla.lvh.me/restaurants`

It still visits `lvh.me/restaurants` and url shows with subdomain.

> ok, lets add known subdomain from route:
>   `platform.lvh.me/restaurants`

It still visits `lvh.me/restaurants` and url shows with subdomain.
The admin and platform subdomains are react the same way.

**2)**
 The same thing happens on `:mobile` and other extra routes

**Route:**

```
namespace :admin, path: '/' do
   root to: 'pages#index'
end

constraints subdomain: 'platform' do
   namespace :platform, path: '/' do
      resources :categories
      root 'pages#index'
   end
end

resources :restaurants
    root 'pages#index'
end
```

Comment: You _might_ need to add `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0` in `development.rb`

Comment: Aren't your routes namespaced? That means that you would need to visit `platform.lvh.me:3000/platform/orders` otherwise it will just go on until it finds a route that fits the request somehow. You could create a catch all, inside the constraint, like `match '*path' => redirect(path: '/platform'), via: :get`

Comment: @JoshBrody if i assign to 0. i will lost my subdomains, literally locks.

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer i use namespace but path is '/', i tried to match with '*path' bit didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails routes by default searches the given URL to find from all routes, no matter subdomain, constraints...

**Sample:**

default url: `lvh.me/restaurants`

if to use any subdomain `admin.lvh.me/restaurants`, It still finds and renders from default url. Admin subdomain dnt have `restaurants` url.

**Solution:**

> Need to add after every subdomain: `match '*a' => redirect(path: '/'), via: :get`
>
> or render other pages like 404/500: `match '*a', :to => 'errors#not_found', via: :get`

Otherwise, will go further and renders from default url.

```
namespace :admin, path: '/' do
   root to: 'pages#index'
   match '*a' => redirect(path: '/'), via: :get
end

constraints subdomain: 'platform' do
   namespace :platform, path: '/' do
      resources :categories
      root 'pages#index'

      match '*a' => redirect(path: '/'), via: :get
   end
end

resources :restaurants
    root 'pages#index'
    match '*a' => redirect(path: '/'), via: :get
end
```